# Filtering targets in NLog

Tags: nlog

I have a logger that configured to multiple targets. Can I filter targets with some conditions?

```
<logger name="actionsLogger" minlevel="Info" writeTo="fileTarget,rmqTarget1,rmqTarget2" />
```

I need to always write actions to fileTarget and in some cases to rmqTarget1 and rmqTarget2. Maybe solution is to create multiple loggers with their own targets. But I can't change source code of the project and recompile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. I have found the solution. FilteringWrapper - https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FilteringWrapper-target. It applies filter for target instead of filter for logger.

```
<target
    xsi:type="FilteringWrapper"
    condition="'${event-context:item=Status}'=='Success'"
    name="rabbitMQFilteringTarget">
    <target
        xsi:type="RabbitMQ"
        name="rabbitMQTarget"
...
    </target>
</target>
```

Comment: This works much better than the conditions, since you can use any layout renderer in the condition for the filtering wrapper, including ${appsetting}

Just make sure that your rules reference the filtering wrapper and not the the target that it contains

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **[Conditions](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/When-Filter#conditions)** on the NLog wiki.

> Conditions are filter expressions used with the *when* filter. They consist of one or more tests. They are used in the *when* filter to determine if an action will be taken.

You can do this with conditions:

```
<logger name="actionsLogger" minlevel="Info" writeTo="fileTarget" />
<logger name="actionsLogger" minlevel="Info" writeTo="rabbitMQTarget">
   <filters defaultAction="Log">
        <when condition="'${event-property:item=Status}'=='Success'" action="Ignore" />
   </filters>
</logger>
```